# Why is rustc producing bunch of files?

Tags: rust

I was just trying to see if Rust is doing bound checking (it does)

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let _x = a[9];
}
```

But when I run this, Rust produces a bunch of garbage files

[image]

What are these files and what are they doing? And when I delete the code and run the program again, they magically disappear.

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: `rustc`, not `cargo` @eggyal

Comment: They look like build artefacts (.o is the object code before linking; and .pdb is debuginfo) that cargo would have rustc place somewhere within the target directory but because you're running rustc directly without specifying otherwise are being placed in the current working directory.  I'm surprised rustc isn't clearing up after itself, though... did you get an ICE?

Comment: Interestingly it cleans itself after fixing the code. I looked into binaries but didn't mean anything to me. And I don't know what an ICE is @eggyal

Comment: ICE = internal compiler error (when the compiler panics and terminates abnormally: it will output a message saying that an ICE occurred).   Perhaps your IDE didn't notice that the files were already deleted and just needs refreshing?

Comment: No IDE is fine. I've just looked into the file itself and they are still there. I think you can also reproduce it. I'm using Windows if that matters @eggyal

Comment: They are all object files btw. You can't read it from the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

by default, rustc has codegen-units > 1, which means it will generate mutiple code units during compilation and finally they are linked to an executable.

You can change the behavior by `-C codegen-units=1`. And you can see all codegen options by `rustc -C help`